# Estimate weighed average for RollingGroupby

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to calculate a weighted average for RollingGroupby object. Unfortunately, I got an error:

```
only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

This is my code:

```
np.random.seed(9999)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(20).reshape(10, 2), columns = ['val1', 'val2'])
df['id'] = np.repeat([1, 2], 5)
df['wt'] = [1, 2] * 5

def weighted_average(data, value, weight):
    return np.average(data[value], weights = data[weight], axis = 0)

dfwavg = df.groupby('id')[['val1', 'wt']]\
        .rolling(window=2, min_periods=1)\
        .apply(weighted_average, 'wt')
```

Does anybody know what's the problem? Thanks.

**EDIT**

Would be great if a solution uses the existing structure (with group.by.rolling.apply). In other words, the best option could be to nest a modified function in `apply()`.

Answer (score 0):

Like this ?

```
pd.concat([(x.val1*x.wt).rolling(window=2,min_periods=1).sum()/x.wt.rolling(window=2,min_periods=1).sum() for _,x in df.groupby('id')])
Out[592]: 
0    0.823389
1    0.295437
2    0.072459
3    0.333050
4    0.445683
5    0.913049
6    0.704820
7    0.317114
8    0.325059
9    0.179366
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. However do you know how to do it, using existing structure (with group.by.rolling.apply)?  In other words, is possible to create a function which could be nested in apply()? Thanks

Comment: @Nicolabo Base on my knowledge I do not know how to make it in with nested - apply